# enable & disable input

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a button that its disabled. But I need that when I click on my iFrame turns enabled and refresh the web page.

This is my button:

```
<input class="" id="deshacer" type="button"  value="Deshacer cambios"  disabled/>
```

I try with this, but doesn't works:

```
 $("#probando").on('click', function () {
   $("#deshacer").attr("disable", false);                             
    });
```

This is my iFrame:

```
<iframe  id="probando" src="<?php echo $url; ?>"  name="probando"></iframe>
```

Comment: You're selecting the attribute `"disable"` which doesn't exist. :) Use `"disabled"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#probando").on('click', function () {
   $("#deshacer").prop("disabled", false);                             
});
```

(`prop` instead of `attr`, and `disabled` instead of `disable`)

Comment: I need 15 reputation to solve the question sorry I cant vote up you :(

Comment: @Lewis LOL no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

When testing this myself, I ran into some trouble getting the `iframe` element itself to accept the `click` event.

Instead, I had to use `.contents()`. (see: https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Here's what worked for me:

```
$("#probando").contents().on('click', function () {
   $("#deshacer").prop("disabled", false);                             
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wk83pqf0/

Answer (score 0):

If your ifram url is not on the exact same domain/subdomain, then your problem is most probably an origin policy one.

As a security measure, javascript can't access the content of an iframe if the iframe's url point to another site/domain. It's also true in the reverse : a JS code inside an iframe can't "climb up" the iframe

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#probando").on('click', function () {
document.getElementById("deshacer").disabled = true;   
location.reload(true);                          
    });
```